# Excel table with expandable records

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Alright, high chance of this being a dumb question, but I hope someone has an answer for me.

Say I have a report for the sales of my 3 products, Cakes, Cookies and Wine. They're all in tables looking something like this:

| Product ID | Total Cookies | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ginderbread | 2 |
| 2 | Chocolate chip | 5 |
| 3 | Cookie type C | 1 |

Using these tables I made a summary table of how many of each product type was sold, like below.

| Category | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| Cookies | 8 |
| Cakes | 11 |
| Wines | 5 |

However, we finally reach my question: I want to now make it so if I click on a record, I can expand it/get a pop-up/something happens that shows me the breakdown of the sales. E.g f I click on "Cookies" the cookie table will show up in some way, shape or form.

My first thought was that Excel's Power Pivot and Pivot Table system would be the answer i'm looking for, but i'm struggling to figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you append all of your data into one table, you can use the drill down feature in the Pivot Table.  When you double click the "Sum of Quantity" column, it will show the applicable data for that row:

[image]

[image]